# Exporting cell contents to text file, with each element being it's own line (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, file, export, cell

A function that I wrote returns a 1xn cell, where n is very large. I'd love for each element along the cell to be exported to a text file without having to do it manually by hand. Is there anyway to do this in MATLAB?

EDIT: Sorry, they're actually string values. Also I would like each element to be on its own line. I apologize for lack of detail.

Comment: What are the cell's contents? Numeric vectors? Matrices? Strings? ...?

Answer (score 1):

If the cells contain **numeric vectors**:

For example

```
myCell = {1:5, [pi log(2)], exp(1:3)};
```

You can use a loop over each cell with [`fprintf`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) as follows:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
for n = 1:numel(myCell)
    fprintf(fid, '%.15f ', myCell{n}); %// print cell's contents in one line
    fseek(fid, -1, 0); %// move one byte back to remove space at the end of line
    fprintf(fid, '\r\n'); %// or just '\n', depending on your system
end
fclose(fid)
```

This produces a text file as follows:

```
1.000000000000000 2.000000000000000 3.000000000000000 4.000000000000000 5.000000000000000
3.141592653589793 0.693147180559945
2.718281828459046 7.389056098930650 20.085536923187668
```

---

If the cells contain **strings**:

For example:

```
myCell = {'Ground control to Major Tom', ...
          'Take your protein pills', ...
          'and put your helmet on'};
```

This case is a little simpler:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
for n = 1:numel(myCell)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', myCell{n}); %// print string followed by \n\r, or \n
end
fclose(fid)
```

This produces a text file as follows:

```
Ground control to Major Tom
Take your protein pills
and put your helmet on
```

Answer (score 0):

**Runthis in the terminal**:

```
for i=1:n 
     dlmwrite(['output_' num2str(i) '.txt'], Cell{i},' ') 
end
```

where 'Cell' is the variable that returns your function